# Send session data to static files in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

One of my **NodeJS routes** looks like this:

```
app.get('/test1/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("index.html");
});
```

And just underneath that I serve the static files:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

I understand what the  first code block does, but not so much the second block.  Although there is a HTML file in the **/public** directory, the **index.html** dependencies - JavaScript and CSS files - are in other folders at the same level of **/public/**.

Besides that, I set up a session variable which holds the username of the user.  I would like to **send** this username to the JavaScript file which is called when index.html is redirected to in the route codeblock.

Is this possible with JavaScript & HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A browser makes a request to your server, `GET /`, the routes are matched in that order, so it is matched with `/test`, and if it doesn't match it goes on to the second route, that is, `express.static` middleware.

The second route serves a static directory in the server. So
`express.static` will match every file in the public directory. so `GET /index.html` will be served as well as `GET /scripts/main.js`.

If you want to send a session variable, you send the user cookies. To send a cookie set it on the response parameter within a middleware.

```
app.use('/test1/', function(req, res) {
  res.cookie('key', 'value');
  res.render('stuff');
});
```